# Using Rails 3 autoload paths isn't loading some folders but is loading others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, class, environment, autoload

I'm using the autoload path's in the application.rb to loads some extra modules and structs.

This is the following bit of code doing it:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/app/controllers/concerns 
  #{config.root}/app/models/concerns 
  #{config.root}/app/jobs/
)
```

The funny thing is both of the "concerns" folders for extending models and controllers are working perfectly.

However the jobs folder is not getting loaded at all.

Is there something special I need to do in order to get a folder in app to be loads or does anyone know why two of these folders are loading and the third isn't?

Comment: Perhaps it's the trailing slash.

Comment: Haha you're right. Pop it in an answer and I'll give you a tick :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try and remove the trailing slash after jobs.

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/app/controllers/concerns 
  #{config.root}/app/models/concerns 
  #{config.root}/app/jobs
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicit load jobs anyway.

http://hakunin.com/rails3-load-paths

Comment: I have the same issue, a new folder under the app is not added to the path and nothing from there is loaded, thus if I try to use something in my `routes.rb` for instance it does not work. I had to `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app')]` in order to make it work